# Python - Print un-nested list into a grid

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a un-nested list of alphabets

```
alphabets = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P']
```

How do I iterate through this list and print the output in a grid format with the row count on the left of every row?

Sample output

```
      Columns
 Rows| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
     -----------------
    1| A | B | C | D |
     -----------------
    2| E | F | G | H |
     -----------------
    3| I | J | K | L |
     -----------------
    4| M | N | O | P |
```

Comment: The `more_itertools` library has the `chunked` and `grouper` functions, which will turn the list into a nested one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working Python 3 solution:

```py
alphabets = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P']
print(' | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |')
print(' -----------------')
i = 0
for letter in alphabets:
    if i % 4 == 0:
        print(str(int(i / 4 + 1)), end="")
    print('| ' + letter + ' ', end="")
    i = i + 1
    if i % 4 == 0:
    print('|\n -----------------')
```

This prints:

```
 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
 -----------------
1| A | B | C | D |
 -----------------
2| E | F | G | H |
 -----------------
3| I | J | K | L |
 -----------------
4| M | N | O | P |
 -----------------
```

The above logic maintains a counter through the letters in the alphabets list.  When a multiple of 4 is reached, it generates a new line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. In the solution that you have given, how do I incorporate the row count into the output? i.e. at the start of every row there's a no. to indicate the row,  see sample output in my question.